# 'openssl/base.h' file not found Firestore

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying use Firestore for my already existing project (also using realtime database). I'm getting `'openssl/base.h' file not found` error.

I tried reinstalling using pod. I updated Xcode. No help there.

Picture of the Error: [image]

I tried creating a new project and installed Firestore with no problem.

This is what I'm doing:

1. `pod Firebase/Firestore` line in podfile
2. `pod install` from command line.
3. `cmd + B` to build the project == `openssl/base.h file not found`

What am I doing wrong here?

(In podfile, I haven't specified a target. I don't know if that could contribute to this problem)

[UPDATE: After reinstalling, it successfully built, and ran - until I opened `hmac.h` file. It's showing the same error only when I open it. The error goes away if I go to any other page and then build and run the project. - weird]

Comment: Still stuck on this in 2023. Any updates? No solutions work for me. It seems to be a conflict with another pod in my Podfile that uses the CocoaSecurity pod.

Answer (score 1):

There was a warning in my Xcode project to "Update to recommended settings"
I did that and reinstalled Firestore `pod Firebase/Firestore` and whola, it worked!!

-- That's just what worked for me.

Comment: Any additional insights on this? Facing the same error, can't get past it

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and this is what I happened to do:

```
cd ios/
rm -rf Pods/
rm Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
```

This will basically clear all the cache and remove the installed Pods. Install Pods once again:

```
pod install
```

If this doesn't resolve the issue, then check if you can find `BoringSSL-GRPC` folder in path `ios/Pods/Headers/Public`. For me, it was missing for some reason. Cocoa Pods wasn't creating it for me.

Check what `openssl version` in Terminal shows:

```
openssl version
LibreSSL 2.6.12
```

It is picking `LibreSSL 2.6.12` instead of expected `OpenSSL 1.1.1g`.

Check path of `openssl`:

```
which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl
```

Go to `~/.bashrc)` (or `~/.zshrc`) and add the following:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

Reload `bashrc` (or `zshrc`):

```
source ~/.bashrc 
source ~/.zshrc (if you are using zsh)
```

Perform `pod install` once again after removing `Pods/` and `Podfile.lock`.

This time, it created `BoringSSL-GRPC` folder and iOS build ran successfully.