# Xcode gRPC-Core Error: 'openssl_grpc/ssl.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

- Xcode: 11.2.1
- Mac: 10.15.2 Beta
- Pod version: 1.8.4

I was trying to ***Archive*** my Mac app on Xcode, then below error in my Xcode:

[image]
[image]

I can compile my app without a problem, just can't archive, I am thinking the issue might be I need to update my pod, when I run command in my terminal

```
pod outdated
```

it shows below info:

[image]

so this is just my guessing.

### Here is an update:

After tried Paul's suggestions, I got a different error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20500#issuecomment-543241775:

- Archive the project in Xcode. It fails with error "openssl_grpc/xxx.h
  file not found".
- In the issue navigator, find the particular error,
  right click, click "Reveal in Log"
- In the build log that's showing
  the error, there's a parentheses with words loaded from
  '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/....'.
- Copy the full
  path and append it with /openssl_grpc.framework for use in the next
  step; should look something like
  /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/......../BoringSSL-GRPC/openssl_grpc.framework
- Archive the project again. When Xcode shows it's building
  "BoringSSL-GRPC", go to terminal, cd into the directory in the above
  step, then run command ln -s Versions/Current/Headers Headers. This
  needs to be done before Xcode finishes building "BoringSSL-GRPC".
- Expect the file-not-found error not showing up this time.

Comment: Hi @Paul , does the command include the period at the end? like `ln -s Versions/Current/Headers Headers. `

Comment: Hi @Paul, I tried the command without period at the end, I think it works, but a new error comes out : `grpc/byte_buffer.h' file not found` I uploaded an image in my question for your reference.

Comment: Hi @Paul, do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Hi @Paul, I created a new question for issue byte_buffer.h  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149991/xcode-11-firebasefirestore-error-grpc-byte-buffer-h-file-not-found

Comment: Might be a comparable answer to this one - just with a different directory ...

Comment: Hi @Paul, I tried the similar way, unfortunately, it is now working...

Answer (score 2):

**I encountered the same issue on my Flutter project on an M1 Mac, and I resolved the problem as follows.**

1- Replace the gRPC dependencies with BoringSSL within the 'Runner' block in the Podfile. You should add this step right below the 'use_frameworks!' and 'use_modular_headers!' lines. You can make the edits as shown below:

pod 'gRPC-Core', :modular_headers => true

pod 'gRPC-C++', :modular_headers => true

**AND POD UPDATE**

2- pod update

[**The sample Podfile is here.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JROPK.png)

Comment: This moved me one step forward however this answer fixed all remaining issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63112942/11170185